# CSS/Bootstrap: How do I make the text inside an SVG on a Bootstrap Carousel responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a bootstrap carousel showing pictures from a trip, but the first slide is a title slide of sorts showing the trip name. The title slide is an SVG with the text in the center. I cannot figure out how to make the text size responsive to the screen size. I've tried following directions for ViewBox and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is my code:

```
{% if adv %}
    <div class = "container py-5">
<!--Carousel -->
        <div class="card mx-auto bg-dark" style="width:100%">
            <div id="picturecarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">                      
                        <svg width="100%" height="700px" viewBox="0 0 100 700"preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
                            <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#a6a6a6" dy=".3em" font-size="100" text-anchor="middle">{{adv.name}}</text>
                        </svg>      
                    </div>

                {% for entry in pics %}        
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="{{entry.picture.url}}" class="d-block w-100 img-responsive img-shrink-700" alt="{{entry.picture_desc}}">
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}

                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#picturecarousel"  data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#picturecarousel"  data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
    
        </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

My backend is in Django, hence the template language.

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally, you should provide a working code snippet, rather than the code from your template, including placeholder images. I did mock up a version of your page using 400x240 images, and if I replaced your SVG line with: `<svg width="400px" height="240px" viewBox="0 0 100 700" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="img-fluid w-100">`, the text would scale to changes in the screen size, although I’m not sure why.

Comment: @RichDeBourke Thank you! I apologize for the hassle of having to make a mock up. It worked and I don't really know why either... how did you figure it out?

Comment: Your code didn’t include any images ([placeholder.com](https://placeholder.com/) is a good source) so I put some of my own images into your code. Since I was using 400x240 images, your SGV was too tall, so I added the same width and height to the SVG image, and that’s when the text became response.